# How to stop tkinter script until button is pressed

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter script that won't cycle to the next text until a button is pressed

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

TabNum = ["1","2","3"]
TabNumInt = 0
Text = tk.Label(text = ("Page number" + TabNum[TabNumInt]))
Text.pack()
def continuefunct():
  global Running
  TabNumInt =+ 1
Continuebtn = Button(window, text = 'Continue', bd = '5', command = continuefunct()).pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

I want this to "print page number [1]" and for the number to increase everytime you press the button until you get to 3. (I know I could have while while TabNumInt =< len(TabNum) but this is just a proof of concept).
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Part of the problem is the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

- `command = continuefunct()` will execute the function immediately without clicking the button. Also nothing will be performed when the button is clicked later.
- need to declare `TabNumInt` as global variable inside the function
- `TabNumInt =+ 1` should be `TabNumInt += 1` instead
- need to update text of the label inside the function

Below is the modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

TabNum = ["1", "2", "3"]
TabNumInt = 0

Text = tk.Label(window, text="Page number "+TabNum[TabNumInt])
Text.pack()

def continuefunct():
    global TabNumInt
    if TabNumInt < len(TabNum)-1:
        TabNumInt += 1
        Text.config(text="Page number "+TabNum[TabNumInt])

tk.Button(window, text='Continue', bd='5', command=continuefunct).pack()

window.mainloop()
```